# undefined reference to `qInitResources_systray()'

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I use qt [official example](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/5.5/examples/widgets/desktop/systray) and get error:

```
/media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qtbase/examples/widgets/desktop/systray/main.cpp:50: undefined reference to `qInitResources_systray()'
```

here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qtbase)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
add_executable(systray main.cpp window.cpp)
target_link_libraries(systray Qt5::Widgets)
```

How to make this example work

Comment: What you forgot is qrc file. You can add it to CMakeLists using qt5_add_resources

Comment: Thanks I had the same issue with `CMake` and this helped. It turned out being a mismatched variable name because I use custom `CMake` helper functions so that Qt4 and Qt5 can be handled by the same CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 4):

according error message `` undefined reference to `qInitResources_systray()' ``, I should use following CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(systray)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qtbase)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
add_executable(systray main.cpp window.cpp systray.qrc)
target_link_libraries(systray Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: This did it for me; I was missing (my equivalent of) `systray.qrc` in the `add_executable` call

Comment: Not only should you add `systray.qrc` in the `add_executable` but also make sure to have CMake variable `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)` set. This will handle `rcc` automatically for Qt targets.